# All Inline buttons in the table (sap.m) are not Emphasized

Tags: button, sapui5

I see a strange behavior in my application as the inline buttons which are part of

> row(item) 20 or beyond in the table are not showing as Emphasized.

[image: Some items are not Emphasized]

I am using a growing list(SingleSelectLeft) which shows 20 items initially and on press of "show more" other items are loaded but they do not have the buttons Emphasized as shown in the image.

Do you think I am missing something here?

Here is my table binding code:

```html
 <Table id="idMasterTable" width="auto" items="{ path: 'mainODataModel>/myCollection'}"
     noDataText="{i18n>masterTableNoDataText}" busyIndicatorDelay="{worklistView>/tableBusyDelay}" growing="true" growingScrollToLoad="true"
     updateFinished="onUpdateFinishedMaster" mode="SingleSelectLeft" inset="false" selectionChange="onMasterTableSelectionChange">
```

I also observed this issue when I filtered the table and removed the filter.
i.e.

- Initially, the list had enabled buttons.
- Upon filtering, I get few items which all have enabled buttons
- When I remove the filter, the items which were not part of the previous filter result are seen disabled.

.

Comment: On the screenshot the buttons are emphasized but the last three buttons seems to be disabled.
Can you please post the relevant parts of your code (xml, binding, controller)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue as there was a disabled property applied in the view with expression binding.